# BlackBoxExplanation or GlassBoxExplanation, which one should I use?

Tags: owl-api, pellet

I'm writing a program that, given an OWL ontology, retrieves all the explanations for a query by using Pellet as reasoner.

To do that the OWLAPI provides a class named `HSTExplanationGenerator` that implements the Hitting Set Tree algorithm to find all the explanations.

When I want to create an instance of `HSTExplanationGenerator` I should give a class that implements the interface `TransactionAwareSingleExpGen`, a class that implements this interface should provide a method to compute an explanation.

Now, OWLAPI provides two classes which implement this interface: `BlackBoxExplanation` and `GlassBoxExplanation`. I have read the code of the two classes. `GlassBoxExplanation` gets the explanation from Pellet, prune it and then converts it into a set of `OWLAxiom`. However, I found it hard to understand what `BlackBoxExplanation` does. The questions are: which one should I use? Which are the main differences between these two classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GlassBoxExplanation` is, as far as I can tell, provided by Pellet, not OWLAPI.

The main difference between a black box explanation and a glass box explanation is that the black box explanation cannot know the reasoner's internals - it is limited to what is available through the `OWLReasoner` interface. In this respect, the definition is no different from black box testing and white box testing in software engineering.

That said, you might want to use the owlexplanation project instead. It is based on laconic explanations, which are a more recent development in OWL entailment explanation than what is available in both OWLAPI and (old versions of) Pellet.

https://github.com/matthewhorridge/owlexplanation

Comment: I know. My comment is a bit late... I saw that the owlexplanation project is stalled, the last commit was 2 years ago and the last compatible OWLAPI version is 4.1.3. I'm trying to use both GlassBoxExplanation and BlackBoxExplanation and GlassBoxExplanation seems to be a lot faster but is limited to Pellet. To the best of your knowledge, are there other projects for axiom pinpointing/justification-explanation reasoning with OWL ontologies?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but if there is an interest in using owlexplanation with a more recent OWLAPI we can sort that out.

Comment: I am one of the developers of the probabilistic reasoner BUNDLE. 
 - [Paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/763f/3c5f35e6a04be3ef0faed626ccb3168e13b0.pdf) 
 - [Bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/machinelearningunife/bundle)

In order to compute the probability BUNDLE needs the set of the explanations. Right now BUNDLE can use only Pellet, I'm writing a modular version of this reasoner to be able to use different reasoners and I need a way to retrieve all the explanations for every possible reasoner.

Comment: I am working on an updated owlexplanation - currently relying on snapshot versions of OWLAPI 5, so it takes a bit of playing about with it. Release details to be decided with the project owner, but in the meantime the project is available here. https://github.com/ignazio1977/owlexplanation Reasoners known to have released OWLAPI 5 versions are Hermit 1.3.8.5xx, Openllet (Pellet fork), JFact. All use the OWLReasoner interface; if you have suggestions for extensions to this interface I'm happy to look at what can be included in future releases.

Comment: Good to hear. I think I'm going to try it. Is owlexplanation based on the Hitting-Set Tree algorithm?

Comment: I'm not cognizant of the theory enough to answer that, but hitting set computation is included in the implementation, so I would guess yes is a likely answer.